# NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID error when registered CNAME to an external domain

Tags: dns, ssl-certificate, amazon-route53, cname

**What I Want to Do:**

"mymy.mydomain.com" points to "otherother.otherdomain.com"
and uses https protocol.

**What I tried:**

I am managing "mydomain.com" with AWS Route53.

And "otherdomain.com" is managed by external service.

I registered a new record on the AWS Route53

- name: mymy.mydomain.com
- type: CNAME
- value: otherdomain.com (otherdomain manager told me to register this value.)

**What I Saw After This..:**

When I accessed to "mymy.mydomain.com",

I could see **NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID** error and a message like "An attacker may be attempting to steal information (such as passwords, messages, credit cards, etc.) from mymy.mydomain.com."

Is there anything I can do in this state? I'd really appreciate your help. Thank you.